# Multiple WebSockets in multithreaded PHP server

Tags: php, multithreading, websocket

I am about to write my first websocket app and I realize that I need a permanent listening service on my server, say, based on [PHP Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets).

However, when the client connects to the server, I want the server to start a thread in order to poll a database and, on something updated, feed the client with the update.

However running PHP 7 on Centos 7 I found out that pthreads are not available.

Is there some better way to achieve my goal?